# Emulating super() in Python 3.x using Python 2.7

Tags: python, beginner, object-oriented, python-2.x, inheritance

Depending on the name of the first argument, `self.__sup` or `cls.__sup` behaves like `super()` in Python 3, while this code is written in Python 2.7. It works for both ordinary methods and class methods(static methods don't use `super()`). See my code for detailed examples:

```
class mySuper(object):
    def __init__(self, cls):
        self.cls = cls
    def __get__(self, obj, cls):
        if obj is None:
            return super(self.cls, cls)
        else:
            return super(self.cls, obj)

class Meta(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, clsdict):
        setattr(cls, '_' + name + '__sup', mySuper(cls))
        super(Meta, cls).__init__(name, bases, clsdict)

# Usage examples:

class A(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta
    def meth(self):
        print 'A.meth(%s)' % self
    @classmethod
    def clsmeth(cls):
        print 'A.clsmeth(%s)' % cls

class B(A):
    def meth(self):
        self.__sup.meth()                # super().meth()
        print 'B.meth(%s)' % self
    @classmethod
    def clsmeth(cls):
        cls.__sup.clsmeth()              # super().clsmeth()
        print 'B.clsmeth(%s)' % cls

class C(A):
    def meth(self):
        self.__sup.meth()
        print 'C.meth(%s)' % self
    @classmethod
    def clsmeth(cls):
        cls.__sup.clsmeth()
        print 'C.clsmeth(%s)' % cls

class D(B, C):
    def meth(self):
        self.__sup.meth()
        print 'D.meth(%s)' % self
    @classmethod
    def clsmeth(cls):
        cls.__sup.clsmeth()
        print 'D.clsmeth(%s)' % cls

d = D()
d.meth()
d.clsmeth()
```

Here is the output:

```
A.meth(<__main__.D object at 0x103c8aed0>)
C.meth(<__main__.D object at 0x103c8aed0>)
B.meth(<__main__.D object at 0x103c8aed0>)
D.meth(<__main__.D object at 0x103c8aed0>)
A.clsmeth(<class '__main__.D'>)
C.clsmeth(<class '__main__.D'>)
B.clsmeth(<class '__main__.D'>)
D.clsmeth(<class '__main__.D'>)
```

I'm sorry if the examples are not very meaningful, but I'm just a beginner. (Maybe emulating `super()` itself is pointless.)

Apart from the "Usage examples", it's just a little snippet, so please tell me **any** problem you can spot in this piece of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, +1 on the idea.  Maybe you could submit this to the Python developers for Python 2.7.13 :)

---

Your super class is called `mySuper`.  Oh, the sound of `my` in a variable name!  Such are the names that are used when describing code to a non-programmer.  We shouldn't allow that in real code.  It is a Super class; that's all there is to it.  If you were to keep `my` in there, however, it should be `PascalCase`, not `mixedCase`.  (That is, `MySuper`, not `mySuper`).  It should be thus for compliance with PEP 8, the Python style guide.

---

Why `Meta`?  Well, obviously it is a meta class, but for what?  The name should describe it more aptly.  This happens to be an incredible meta class, so call it `SuperMeta` ;)

---

Instead of a couple concatenations, use string formatting:

```
setattr(cls, '_{}__sup'.format(name), Super(cls))
```